# Delete Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

Because I am an idiot, I accidentally installed a rails app in root on my Linux installation. In addition to this just sounding awful, trying to make any others anywhere else results in Rails telling me I can't make an app on a subdirectory of another app. I've already manually deleted the app files, but I see this isn't enough. How do I convince Rails I really didn't want it to be there?

---

Fittingly, I don't have enough reputation to answer this question myself, but my own ineptitude reveals that there were simply more files left to delete that I missed.

Comment: As the saying goes, *stuff* happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for a .git directory in your root, if it belongs to the rails app, kill it.

Comment: _Just_ in cast OP isn't sure, the .git directory is hidden. If you don't see it, first turn on hidden folders.